# Submit button is not working eveb if I have entered input data inside form

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I am trying to request data from a whois server and display it on my page. It works fine if I hit enter but the Submit button is not working.

The url of the page:

`../whois.php`

The url I want after hitting submit

`../whois.php?domain=somewebsite.com`

This is my HTML code.

```
<section class="calltoaction section_sapce cover-image" data-image-src="images/subbanners/4.jpg">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row cta-content">
                <div class="offerdescription">
                    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
                        <b><label for="domain">
                            <h2 class="text-uppercase text-center">Domain/IP Address:</h2>
                            <p class=" text-center">Free WhoIs Lookup for any domain/IP. It's free and easy.</p>
                            </label>
                        </b>    
                        <div>
                            <form class="form-inline domainsearch">
                                <div class="row searchdomain">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-right:0; padding-left:0;">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="domain" id="domain" placeholder="Enter Your Domain/IP" value="<?=$domain;?>" required onFocus="if (this.value == 'Enter your domain/IP') {this.value = '';}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter your domain/IP';}" value="Enter your domain/IP" > 
                                    </div>  
                                    <div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-right:0; padding-left:0">    
                                        <button class="btn btn-new btn-lg" style="width:100%" type="button" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?".$domain;?>" name="button">Lookup</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>  
                    </form> 
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>      
    </div>
</section>
```

Can you please help me fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use button `type="submit"` instead of `type="button"`
like this

```
<button class="btn btn-new btn-lg" style="width:100%" type="submit" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?".$domain;?>" name="button">Lookup</button>
```

Comment: Should I keep the action empty?

Comment: You don't need any action on the `button` (in fact it doesn't do anything). The action makes sense only on the `form`. You can add an `action=""` there to make it explicit, if you want. The `domain` parameter will already get sent as query parameter because that's how forms handle their values when sent via `GET` (which is the default method).

Answer (score 1):

the button needs to be have a type submit

Answer (score 0):

Try defining action in form and not in button and change type of the button from button to submit

Comment: The action is not necessary because the default action would be a relative URL consisting of an empty string, which is basically the current URL, and the input is already getting sent as query parameter.